# Laravel unique validation rule ignore for array incoming data

Tags: laravel

```
'email' => 'required|unique:users,email,'.$user->id
```

We all know that while we update an instance in database we should ignore its id when we are using unique validation rule, like the above example.
Now in my application I have an Agency model and an Employee model and each Agency has many Employee.
In my application I have a form to create and update Agencies and Employees.
Data sent by this form :

```
$request->validate([
    'agency.name' => 'required|string',
    'agency.phone' => 'required|string|unique:agencies,phone,'.$agency->id,
    .
    .
    .
    'employees.*.first_name' => 'required|string',
    'employees.*.last_name' => 'required|string',
    'employees.*.email' => 'required|unique:employees,email'
]);
```

Now, validating `agency.phone` is quite easy, because we only have 1 agency and we can easily pass `$agency->id` to ignore unique validation rule for this instance.

```
'agency.phone' => 'required|string|unique:agencies,phone,'.$agency->id
```

Now the problem that I'm facing is that I have multiple employees in my incoming data and I cannot use an id to ignore

```
'employees.*.email' => 'required|unique:employees,email' // cannot add $employee->id here in order to ignore while updating
```

I do have id of each employee in my incoming data, so how can I use it to ignore laravel validation rule  for array incoming data like in this example?

**HELP**
The output of `dd($request->all())` is :

```
array:2 [
  "agency" => array:7 [
    "id" => 5
    "name" => "xxxxxxx"
    "manager_name" => null
    "manager_phone" => null
    "phone" => null
    "created_at" => "2020-10-23T00:53:13.000000Z"
    "updated_at" => "2020-10-23T00:53:13.000000Z"
  ]
  "employees" => array:1 [
    0 => array:6 [
      "id" => 1
      "first_name" => "John"
      "last_name" => "Doe"
      "email" => "doctor@doctor.com"
      "created_at" => "2020-10-23T00:53:13.000000Z"
      "updated_at" => "2020-10-23T00:53:13.000000Z"
    ]
  ]
]
```

Comment: You can use custom validation rule, do you have all employee id's as an array?

Comment: I updated the question you can see incoming data from my form @sta

Comment: Try this `'employees.*.email' =>['required', Rule::unique( 'employees')->ignore( 'employees.*.id') ],`

Comment: This may also work `'employees.*.email' => 'required|unique:employees,email,' . 'employees.*.id',`

Comment: @sta you should never pass user data to the ignore, this will make it vulnerable to an SQL injection attack.

Answer (score 1):

Just validate twice! :)

You could first validate all the things that don't require you to know the Employee IDs. Like so:

```php
<?php

$request->validate([
    'agency.name' => 'required|string',
    'agency.phone' => 'required|string|unique:agencies,phone,'.$agency->id,
    // ...
    'employees.*.first_name' => 'required|string',
    'employees.*.last_name' => 'required|string',
    'employees.*.email' => 'required'
]);
```

Then you could do a `foreach` loop over the employee IDs, and construct your unique email rules. Assuming you have your Employee IDs in a variable like `$ids` and they are ordered the same way as your request data, you could do something like this:

```php
<?php

$uniqueEmailRules = [];
foreach($ids as $key => $id) {
    $uniqueEmailRules['employees.' . $key . '.email'] = 'unique:employees,email,' . $id;
}

$request->validate($uniqueEmailRules);
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid validating twice, you can do something like:

```
$request->validate([
    'employees.*.email' => Rule::forEach(function ($value, $attribute, $data) {
        $idKey = Str::replace('email', 'id', $attribute);
        return [
            'email', 'required', Rule::unique('employees')->ignore($data[$idKey])
        ];
    }),
]);
```

Within the callback, `$value` will give you the email address you're validating, `$attribute` will give you the key of the validation array eg `employees.1.email` and then `$data` gives you all of the validation entries for that rule.